# Invalid Column Name When Group By Nested Select

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have the following code, when I run it as is it will return to me the data I would like:

```
select tagid, 
  (select TOP 1 Locations.CostCenter
  from item
  inner join transactions on transactions.itemid = item.id 
  inner join recvlocationmapping on recvlocationid = transactions.locationid 
  left outer join locations on locations.id = servicelocationid  
  where tagid = c.TagID
  and costcenter != '' 
  and Costcenter is not null 
  order by transdate desc) as CostCenter
from item as c where createddate between '07-01-2012' and '07-05-2012'
```

The problem comes when I want to add a group by to one of the columns. It then throws a error saying the column doesn't exist, but when I run the query without the Group By the column and name exist.

Here is the group by code that I'm having issues with:

```
select Count(tagid), 
  (select TOP 1 Locations.CostCenter
  from item
  inner join transactions on transactions.itemid = item.id 
  inner join recvlocationmapping on recvlocationid = transactions.locationid 
  left outer join locations on locations.id = servicelocationid  
  where tagid = c.TagID
  and costcenter != '' 
  and Costcenter is not null 
  order by transdate desc) as CostCenter
from item as c where createddate between '07-01-2012' and '07-05-2012'
group by CostCenter
```

I think it's an issue with how I'm returning the data, but I don't know enough about SQL to figure out how to fix it.

Comment: you'll probably need to put that whole clause into the GROUP BY; I don't think it can use the alias.

Answer (score 2):

Aliases declared in `select ...` part cannot be used in `group by`. You either have to duplicate nested select in `group by` or use something like this:

```
select Count(q.tagid), q.CostCenter
from
    (select 
       tagid, 
       (select TOP 1 Locations.CostCenter
           from item
           inner join transactions on transactions.itemid = item.id 
           inner join recvlocationmapping on recvlocationid = transactions.locationid 
           left outer join locations on locations.id = servicelocationid  
           where tagid = c.TagID
           and costcenter != '' 
           and Costcenter is not null 
           order by transdate desc
       ) as CostCenter
       from item as c where createddate between '07-01-2012' and '07-05-2012'
    ) q
group by q.CostCenter
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of the T-SQL `APPLY` functionality here, it is similar to the correlated subquery you have used but can be referenced multiple times without repeating the same code, and can also return multiple columns/rows if required.

```
SELECT  COUNT(tagid), 
        CostCenter
FROM    item as c 
        OUTER APPLY
        (   SELECT  TOP 1 Locations.CostCenter
            FROM    item
                    INNER JOIN transactions 
                        ON transactions.itemid = item.id 
                    INNER JOIN recvlocationmapping 
                        ON recvlocationid = transactions.locationid 
                    INNER JOIN locations 
                        ON locations.id = servicelocationid  
            WHERE   tagid = c.TagID
            AND     costcenter != '' 
            ORDER BY transdate DESC
        ) AS CostCenter
WHERE   createddate BETWEEN '07-01-2012' AND '07-05-2012'
GROUP BY CostCenter
```

I've also touched up a couple of things on your subquery, I changed the `LEFT JOIN` on locations to an `INNER JOIN` since you had `AND CostCenter IS NOT NULL` therefore a `LEFT JOIN` was not required and `INNER JOIN`s will perform better. Secondly `AND CostCenter IS NOT NULL` was redundant following `AND CostCenter != ''` because `NULL != ''`

**EDIT**

Upon further thought I think you can remove the correlated subqueries from it completely and get the same result using `JOINS`. This should result in more efficient execution:

```
;WITH CostCenter AS
(   SELECT  TagID, CostCenter, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY TagID ORDER BY TransDate DESC) AS RowNumber
    FROM    item
            INNER JOIN transactions 
                ON transactions.itemid = item.id 
            INNER JOIN recvlocationmapping 
                ON recvlocationid = transactions.locationid 
            INNER JOIN locations 
                ON locations.id = servicelocationid  
    WHERE   costcenter != '' 
)
SELECT  COUNT(TagID), CostCenter
FROM    Item
        INNER JOIN CostCenter
            ON Item.TagID = CostCenter.TagID
            AND RowNumber = 1
WHERE   createddate BETWEEN '07-01-2012' AND '07-05-2012'
GROUP BY CostCenter
```